# How to connect a 2nd display to iPad, or to stream iPad screen to a computer or another iPad?

Tags: ipad, display, ipados, ergonomics

For ergonomics reasons, I need to work with an iPad in the following setup:

A 2nd display needs to be connected to it to function as a display, so that i can lay the iPad flat on the desk and use an Apple Pencil to control things on the iPad, while looking at the upright display.

Basically I need to see what’s on the iPad screen on an upright display while controlling it with something on which a tap can register as a click, and you can drag things across the screen without pressing down. I tried the Magic trackpad, but even though it lets you tap to click, dragging things across the screen requires pressing down the entire time.

I looked into this a bit and it seems that the “SideCar” feature is only for a Mac to use an iPad as a 2nd display and not vice versa.

How can I solve this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You never mentioned which  iPad nor the version of iPadOS you’re using.  Have you tried connecting connecting your display using the USB-C or Lightning to AV adapter?  What were your results?  You say “connect a second display,” how many displays do you want to connect in total?

Comment: @Allan 11 inch iPad pro, latest iPadOS. By “2nd display” I just meant a display in addition to the iPad’s screen. I think I wrote it like that because while I was searching for help, there were Apple’s official pages titled “using an iPad as a second display to your Mac”

Comment: If you just want to connect an external display to an iPad, you need the adapter I mentioned before. Then just connect it and use it like you described

Answer (score 0):

You can use an adapter like [this one](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07TVSLDND) to connect to VGA or HDMI. If you need DisplayPort, use something like [this](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B081VKXFSC).

These are just general items and are not particular product suggestions.